# How to translate setxkbmap to xinitrc config

Tags: x11, xorg, x-server, xinit, setxkbmap

I am setting my keyboard layout using this command on every startup:

```
setxkbmap us,cz -variant ,ucw -option grp:caps_switch
```

How can I write this configuration in to `xinitrc` file so xserver loads it natively ?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

The file *$HOME/.xinitrc* is a shell script, which is executed by [**startx**(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/startx) and [**xinit**(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xinit). You can simply add the related command to *$HOME/.xinitrc*. Of course, if you are using [autostart X at login](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xinit#Autostart_X_at_login) (no display manager), that file will typically look like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# ... some commands...

exec some_program_or_wm
```

The only thing worth noting is that the call to **setxkbmap** should be inserted before the final [exec(1p)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec), because that builtin replaces the shell process with its argument (no commands after `exec` will be executed). Thus:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# ... some commands...

setxkbmap us,cz -variant ,ucw -option grp:caps_switch

exec some_program_or_wm
```